# Applying filter (e.g., moving average) on Binomial distributed random values

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, moving-average

I start with Binomial distributed random values with known $N$ and success probability $p$. I can easily estimate PMF and CDF of such distribution. Now assume these Binomial distributed random values go through a filter, for example moving average. Is the PDF of the new distribution well defined?

Context: my goal is to find a signal / peak hidden in the noise described by Binomial distribution, however the data is correlated with some wavelet first (so not quite moving average, but close)

Comment: You might need to give us more information on your moving average.  Your binomial values are integers from $0,...,N$ so if your moving average uses non-integer coefficients (which are not multiples of each other) then you might find that the MA value deterministically implies the binomial values.